# Can I attach/bind text to elements in Raphael?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm brand new to Raphael, and I was wondering if there's a way I can draw a rect, and draw text inside of it and attach it somehow, so that when I move and scale the rect, the text moves and scales as well? If not, how could I achieve that effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to use [Sets](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.setStart) like this:

```
var paper = Raphael("holder", 200, 200);
paper.setStart();
paper.rect(-50, -50, 100, 100);
paper.text(0, 0, "hello");
var st = paper.setFinish();
st.transform("r10").translate(100, 100);
```

[(On JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/sirhc/QftJd/)

**Tip**: Note that you have to track the rotation axis on your own if you're not using `0,0` as the center. I personally like to keep it at `0,0` and then translate it to wherever I want.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using this instead. The size of the rectangle gets resized as and when the text length increases.

```
var recttext = paper.set();
el = paper.rect(0, 0, 300, 200);
text = paper.text(0,10, "Hi... This is a test to check whether the rectangle dynamically changes its size.").attr({"text-anchor":"start",fill:'#ff0000',"font-size": 14});
text1=paper.text(0,30,"hi").attr({"text-anchor":"start",fill: '#ff0000',"font-size": 14});
recttext.push(el);
recttext.push(text);
recttext.push(text1);
alert(recttext.getBBox().width);
alert(recttext.getBBox().height);
var att = {width:recttext.getBBox().width,height:recttext.getBBox().height};
el.attr(att);
recttext.translate(700,400);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Raphael's 'data' method to bind two elements together.

```
paper = Raphael(paper, 400, 400);
var circle = paper.circle(50, 50, 20)
.attr({
"fill": "#0ff"
})
.data("initialR", 20);

var labelize = function (shape, label) {
if (!label) {
    var label = "StackOverflow"
};
var label = paper.text(shape.attr("cx"), shape.attr("cy"), label)
    .attr({
    "opacity": 0
});
shape.data("label", label);

var hoverIn = function () {
    this.animate({
        "r": 100
    }, 500, "<>");
    this.data("label").animate({
        "opacity": 1
    }, 500);
};
var hoverOut = function () {
    this.animate({
        "r": this.data("initialR")
    }, 500, "<>");
    this.data("label").animate({
        "opacity": 0
    }, 500);
};
shape.hover(hoverIn, hoverOut, shape, shape);
return shape;
};

circle = labelize(circle, "CaptSaltyJack");
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hNcef/)